Will there be an end to new discoveries in mathematics?
Are new discoveries in math going someday to disappear? Will we reach the last theorem someday? This is somewhat similar to the question "do we discover or invent math? because it seems we might run out of things to discover or it could be very well that we run out of ideas.
Will there be an end to new discoveries in mathematics?

If you are asking whether someday math might attain a perfect form such that there are no discoveries left to be made, I think that's in the same category as the people who declared that nothing remained to be patented. While it does not seem impossible that we might someday run out of new questions to ask that math is useful for answering, I don't see that happening in the next millennium. And if even if we somehow achieved that, math would remain a useful tool so I can't see why you think it might disappear.

@shindemo: I presume you meant exploration or explanation rather than exploitation.

I've edited the grammar to stave off VTC based on a complaint of a lack of clarity. Feel free to roll back.

@keshlam I was placing myself in the very far future (not just the next millennium)

It's hard to see how or why new mathematics would stop.
In a theoretical sense, math obeys the generative principle. That means, we can continually create new mathematical systems by articulating new sets of axioms. Since at least Euclid and his geometry, mathematicians have been exploring those systems finding new theorems, and mathematicians have been building new systems with new axioms.
In particular, there is a field of mathematics called reverse mathematics whose purpose is simply to find new axioms. Thus, when mathematicians are unhappy with one system (like ZF), they find and add a new axiom to it (like the axiom of choice in ZFC).
Even within a formal system, the system obeys rules of production allowing all sorts of patterns and conjectures to arise. Consider all of the theorems and conjectures that surround primes. The discovery of the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the non-finitary nature of primes raises questions like the twin prime conjecture and the Goldbach conjecture. And as new patterns are found, new questions spring into existence.
So, perhaps there is some theoretical end of the road for mathematics; but given the generative principle and results like Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem (which tells us roughly mathematical systems cannot be complete and consistent), it seems like mathematicians have their work cut out for them for the foreseeable future.

@shindemo Happy NY to you too! :D I provide a niche service. I warrant neither my own expertise, nor aspire to a simple response. Others in the ecosystem are encouraged to differentiate themselves in terms simplicity and accessibility, and certainly the OP is encouraged to check the links and come to their own opinions. Besides, it keeps the world safer keeping me distracted from writing some sort of manifesto. May the wind fill your sails, and the woods fill your belly!

Possibly we (humans, or AI) may run out of patterns ?

@niobium Unlikely. See the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion .
